# How do I make a custom pipe available to all components in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

Let's say I create a custom rainbowize pipe, which wraps each letter in a span with a random color of the rainbow as the css color prop. I'd like to be able to use this custom pipe in all components in my app. Currently, I'm importing pipes into each component like this

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

import { RainbowizePipe } from '../pipes/rainbowize';

@Component({
    'pipes': [RainbowizePipe]
})
```

and using it in templates like this

```
<p>{{text | rainbowize}}</p>
```

So that's great, I have rainbow colored text. However, it would be nice to only need to import the Rainbowize pipe into the app once and then have it globally available.

Is there a recommended Angular 2 / Typescript approach to making a custom pipe globally available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your custom pipe to [PLATFORM_PIPES](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/compiler/PLATFORM_PIPES-let.html) so is available to your whole application.

```
bootstrap(App, [provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: RainbowizePipe, multi:true})]);
```

This way you won't have to explicitely add them in the `pipes` property of your components.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FZ5vkEfV6UuWPXQ92Gr?p=preview) with an example working.